# Epson Perfection V19 scanner unrecognized

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson, scanning

I have an Epson perfection v19 scanner. I have `iscan-data`, `iscan`, and `sane` installed. When I run iscan, it says:

> check the printer status

Xsane also does not recognize it.

How do I scan?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install also iscan-plugin-package

Download it from [Epson drivers site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).
You need to search your model, then click `iscan-plugin-package`, accept license and download a deb package that matches your architecture.

After you install it, all programs like iscan, xsane will recognize the scanner and scan.

Comment: It was right under my nose.

Comment: Confirmed functionality. This scanner works perfectly on UBUNTU 16.04 LTS